# rosserial and motor controllers

Tags: ros, rosserial, motor-controller

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am a little bit confused about the usage of rosserial. Is rosserial supposed to be used only for running it only inside embedded systems such as microcontrollers?

What if I have a motor controller on my robot, and I want to write ROS code to interface with it (the motor controller uses serial commands for communication)? Can I just have rosserial running on the robot's laptop in order to communicate with the motor controller?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/141011/rosserial-and-motor-controllers/) by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 803 on 2014-03-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can always use standard serial I/O for communicating with serial devices from a ROS node; ROS serial is a mechanism through which you can program any two systems that can communicate via serial to use ROS' API instead of bothering to deal with low level serial port I/O.

Specifically, in your case your motor controller will most probably come with a SDK of sorts that deals with sending motor commands over a serial port. You would simply use that API within your ROS node on your laptop to communicate with the motor controller.

ROS Serial would be useful if you were to write your motor controller from scratch on say an Arduino, and wanted to easily communicate with ROS devices over the serial port using the ROS Serial API.

---

Originally posted by [ICodeRaven](https://answers.ros.org/users/793/icoderaven/) with karma: 76 on 2014-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) on 2014-03-17**:
I see. Thank you